# unexpected ArraysIndexOutOfBounds exception occurring in my code

Tags: java, arrays

This java program is basically for managing a class of n students. it has various functions such as attendance etc, but on compilation there is an ArraysIndexOutOfBounds exception, who's reason , I can't compute. please help.

```
import java.util.*;

class CLManager
{

    static Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner dd = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner ii = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner cc = new Scanner(System.in);


    int i, j, k, OnRoll;
    String PRemark[] = {"Good Job !", "Excellent !", "Well Done !", "Phenomenal !", "Amazing Performance !", "Keep it up !"};
    String NRemark[] = {"Can do better !", "More effort needed !", "Work harder !", "Needs practice !", "Keep Trying !", "Don't lose hope !"};


    CLManager()
    {
        i=0;
        j=0;
        k=0;

        System.out.println("Enter total no. of students in class");
        OnRoll = ii.nextInt();
    }

    int marks[]  = new int[OnRoll];
    int rollno[] = new int[OnRoll];
    int ranks[]  = new int[OnRoll];

    String names[]   = new String[OnRoll];
    String remarks[] = new String[OnRoll];
    String grades[]  = new String[OnRoll];

    CLManager(int OnRoll)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter names of students in class");
        for(i=0; i<OnRoll; i++)
        {
            names[i] = ss.nextLine(); //error occurs here
            rollno[i] = (i+1);
        }
    }


    void Attendance()
    {
        int P=0, A=0;
        char rec;
        System.out.println("Enter P for present and A for absent");

        for(i=0; i<OnRoll; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(names[i]);
            rec = cc.next().charAt(0);
            if(rec=='P'||rec=='p')
            {
                P++;
            }
            else
            {
                A++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Present :\t"+P);
        System.out.println("Absent  :\t"+A);
        System.out.println("On Roll :\t"+OnRoll);
    }


    void GradeMarksRemarks()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter marks/100");
        for(i=0; i<OnRoll; i++)
        {
            marks[i] = ii.nextInt();
        }

        for(i=0; i<OnRoll; i++)
        { 
            if(marks[i]<=100&&marks[i]>=90)
            {
                grades[i]="A+";
                remarks[i]="Highly Commendable";
            }
            else if(marks[i]<=89&&marks[i]>=80)
            {
                grades[i]="A";
                remarks[i]="Commendable";
            }
            else if(marks[i]<=79&&marks[i]>=70)
            {
                grades[i]="B+";
                remarks[i]="Very Good";
            }
            else if(marks[i]<=69&&marks[i]>=60)
            {
                grades[i]="B";
                remarks[i]="Good";
            }
            else if(marks[i]<=59&&marks[i]>=50)
            {
                grades[i]="C+";
                remarks[i]="Average";
            }
            else if(marks[i]<=49&&marks[i]>=40)
            {
                grades[i]="C";
                remarks[i]="Borderline";
            }
            else if(marks[i]<=39&&marks[i]>=35)
            {
                grades[i]="D+";
                remarks[i]="Below Average";
            }
            else if(marks[i]<=35)
            {
                grades[i]="D";
                remarks[i]="Fail";
            }
        }
    }


    void GenerateRanks()
    {
        int a=0, b=0 ,m=0 , n=0;
        String p="", q="", x="", y="";

        for(i=0; i<OnRoll; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<OnRoll-1-i; j++)
            {
                if(marks[j]>marks[j+1])
                {
                    marks[j] = a;
                    marks[j+1] = b;
                    marks[j] = b;
                    marks[j+1] = a;
                    a=0; b=0;

                    rollno[j] = m;
                    rollno[j+1] = n;
                    rollno[j] = n;
                    rollno[j+1] = m;
                    m=0; n=0;

                    names[j] = p;
                    names[j+1] = q;
                    names[j] = p;
                    names[j+1] = q;
                    p=""; q="";

                    grades[j] = x;
                    grades[j+1] = y;
                    grades[j] = y;
                    grades[j+1] = x;
                    x=""; y="";
                }
            }
        }

        for(i=0; i<OnRoll; i++)
        {
            ranks[i] = (i+1); 
        }
    }


    void DisplayRanks()
    {
        System.out.println("Rank\t\tName\t\tGrade");
        for(i=0; i<OnRoll; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(ranks[i]+"\t\t"+names[i]+"\t\t"+grades[i]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    void DisplayReport()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter roll no.");
        int roll = ii.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Rank\t\tName\t\tGrade");
            System.out.print(roll+"\t\t"+names[roll]+"\t\t"+ranks[roll]+"\t\t"+grades[roll]);
        if(marks[roll]>=65)
        {
            System.out.println(PRemark[(int)((Math.random())*6)]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(NRemark[(int)((Math.random())*6)]);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        CLManager fn = new CLManager();
        System.out.println("Welcome to Class Manager!");



        inf :
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("For Attendance, press A");
            System.out.println("For Grades and Marks, press M");
            System.out.println("For generation, press G\nFor Positions, press P");
            System.out.println("For Report, press R\nFor Exit, press E");
            System.out.println();
            char ch = cc.next().charAt(0);

            switch(ch)
            {
                case 'E' :
                    System.out.println("TERMINATED");
                    break inf;

                case 'A' :
                    fn.Attendance();
                    break;

                case 'M' :
                    fn.GradeMarksRemarks();
                    break;

                case 'G' :
                    fn.GenerateRanks();
                    break;

                case 'P' :
                    fn.DisplayRanks();
                    break;

                case 'R' :
                    fn.DisplayReport();
                    break;

                default : System.out.println("INVALID INPUT");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for using ! :):)");
    }
}
```

I fail to understand why the problem arises in the first place. Is there some mistake that has occurred on my part? The code seems all right to me but for some reason whenever I start entering names, or even letters in the array names[] I get the error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  While posting 100+ lines of code in a single question is generally never a good idea on this site, at the very least you should highlight where in your code the actual problem is.

Comment: Why don't you paste the StackTrace, it is much easier to debug that way

Comment: which line is throwing the error?

Comment: `CLManager(int OnRoll)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter names of students in class");
        for(i=0; i<OnRoll; i++)
        {
            names[i] = ss.nextLine(); //error occurs here
            rollno[i] = (i+1);
        }
    }`

Comment: your `names` is initialized with `null`s

Comment: Four scanners? You should need only one. Not that it answers your question, though.

Answer (score 0):

You have this error, because your `names` array initialized with `OnRoll`default value that equals `0`, because you haven't provide it.

You need to put this initialization inside your constructor:

```
marks[]  = new int[OnRoll];
rollno[] = new int[OnRoll];
ranks[]  = new int[OnRoll];

names[]   = new String[OnRoll];
remarks[] = new String[OnRoll];
grades[]  = new String[OnRoll];
```

Comment: it defined as int, so it will have default value 0

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error  because when program enters the second constructor `OnRoll` remains **uninitialized**, so make this modification

```
    CLManager(int OnRoll)
    {

        this.OnRoll = OnRoll;  // add only this line of code
        System.out.println("Enter names of students in class");
        for(i=0; i<OnRoll; i++)
        {
            names[i] = ss.nextLine(); //error occurs here -> resolved
            rollno[i] = (i+1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because your second constructor was never called where you took all name input.

You should do this way,

```
CLManager()
{
    i=0;
    j=0;
    k=0;

    System.out.println("Enter total no. of students in class");
    OnRoll = ii.nextInt();
    initializeAllArraysAndCollectNames(OnRoll);
}

int marks[];
int rollno[];
int ranks[];

String names[];
String remarks[];
String grades[];

void initializeAllArraysAndCollectNames(int OnRoll)
{
    marks  = new int[OnRoll];
    rollno = new int[OnRoll];
    ranks  = new int[OnRoll];
    names   = new String[OnRoll];
    remarks = new String[OnRoll];
    grades  = new String[OnRoll];
    System.out.println("Enter names of students in class");
    for(i=0; i<OnRoll; i++)
    {
        names[i] = ss.nextLine(); //error occurs here
        rollno[i] = (i+1);
    }
}
```

Here, after taking `OnRoll` input then arrays are initializing and taking name input.

You can find full code here, https://ideone.com/Lrb7yZ